# Why is this test for inclusion of value in array is failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, shoulda

The following test is always failing, but it's not clear why.

```
# entry_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Entry do
  before { @entry = build_stubbed :entry }
  subject { @entry }

  it { should respond_to :published }

  describe 'validation' do
    it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:published).in_array([true, false]) }
  end
end

# entry.rb
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :published, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
end
```

The failure:

```
1) Entry validation should ensure inclusion of published in [true, false]
     Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:published).in_array([true, false]) }
       [true, false] doesn't match array in validation
     # ./spec/models/entry_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entry do
    published true
  end
end
```

I'm ommitted a couple of other attributes, but there is nothing special going on there, and they shouldn't impact the code.

Comment: I've never seen validation tests used with `build_stubbed`. Have you tried the test with a regular instance?

Comment: Yes, I have. Using `build` and `create` strategies. This is strange, and it's not the first project where this has happened.

Comment: So, specifically, you've used `@entry = create(:entry)` and you get the same error?

Comment: You can always modify the gem to print out the values involved to see where the issue is (note, I mistakenly said line 98, but it's line 90 on the version of the source I referenced).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be [a bug with shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/291). The suggested workaround is to use `allow_value` matcher instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `:published` attribute is **`nil`** which is treated as `false` but it isn't the explicit `false` value you have in your array.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How am I supposed to get the test passing then? Try a different test? Validate for presence?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton is your attribute's value nil? If yes, then this value doesn't exist in your array. You must redefine your test.

Comment: I have it set in factory girl as such: `published true` that means it aught to be true in the test, no?